# Can't parse a second table with beautifulsoup even if the first one works?

Tags: python, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse tables using beautifulsoup. The first one on my page was easy but I cannot parse a similar table on the same page. I do not understand why.

Here is the code. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = urllib2.urlopen("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/956261/poftext.html")
contentHTML = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(contentHTML)

tableUserDetails = soup.find("table", {"class" : "user-details"})

i = 0
tableUserDetailsList = []
for row in tableUserDetails.findAll('tr'):
    for col in row.findAll('td'):
        contentTd = col.contents[0].string.strip()

        if contentTd:
            print "TD Number %d : %s" % (i, contentTd)
            tableUserDetailsList.append(contentTd)
            i += 1

# This first table is OK
print tableUserDetailsList


# But now this one
tableUserDetails = soup.find("table", {"class" : "secondpart"})

i = 0
tableUserDetailsList = []
for row in tableUserDetails.findAll('tr'):
    for col in row.findAll('td'):
        contentTd = col.contents[0].string.strip()

        if contentTd:
            print "TD Number %d : %s" % (i, contentTd)
            tableUserDetailsList.append(contentTd)
            i += 1

print tableUserDetailsList

# The list is empty :(
```

Here is a simplified version of the HTML code that I am trying to parse:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>
        French.Kiss
        Sorties, Sport, Voyages, Nouvelles Expériences</title> 

</head>
<body style='background-color: #fff;' leftMargin='0' topMargin='0' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' link='#1E55D6' vlink='#1E55D6'  TEXT='#6551b0'>

            <table class="user-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="headline txtBlue size15" style="width:80px">
                        About
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:10px">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="txtGrey size15">
                        Fume occasionnellement with Silhouette mince
                    </td>
                    <td width="25px;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="headline txtBlue size15">
                        City
                    </td>
                    <td class="txtGrey size15">
                        Paris Ile-de-France
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="headline txtBlue size15">
                        Details
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:10px">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="txtGrey size15">
                        26 year old Un homme, 185cm, Sans religion
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="headline txtBlue size15">
                        Ethnicity
                    </td>
                    <td class="txtGrey size15">
                        Caucasienne Balance with Châtains
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="headline txtBlue size15">
                        Intent
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:10px">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="txtGrey size15">
                        French.Kiss Cherche une relation amoureuse.
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="headline txtBlue size15" style="width:90px">
                        Education
                    </td>
                    <td class="txtGrey size15">
                        Diplôme universitaire/Licence
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="headline txtBlue size15">
                        Personnalité
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:10px">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="txtGrey size15">

                    </td>   <td>
                    </td>
                <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size15">Profession </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size15">
                                Visioconférence</span>
                        </td>
                </tr>

            </table> 





















                <table width="85%" class="secondpart">
                    <tr height="25px">
                        <td width="200px">
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">I am Seeking a</span>
                        </td>
                        <td width="300px">
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Une femme</span>
                        </td>
                        <td width="25px">
                        </td>
                        <td width="200px">
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">For</span>
                        </td>
                        <td width="200px">
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Sorties</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25px">
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14"><a href='needs_test.aspx'>Needs Test</a></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14"><a href='needs_test.aspx'>


                                <a href="needs_view.aspx?id=38028200">View
                                    his
                                    relationship needs</a></a></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14"><a href='poftest.aspx'>Chemistry</a></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14"><a href='poftest.aspx'>

                                <a href="personality.aspx?id=26&user_id=41724176" rel="nofollow">View
                                    his
                                    chemistry results</a></a></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25px">
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Do you drink?</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Occasionnellement</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Do you want children?</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Non divulgué</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25px">
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Marital Status</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Célibataire</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Do you do drugs?</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Non</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr height="25px">
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Pets </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Aucun</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Eye Color</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Bruns</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr height="25px">
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Do you have a car? </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                N/A</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Do you have children?</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Non</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25px">
                        <td>
                         <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Longest Relationship</span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Plus de 2 ans</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table> 
</body>
</html>
```

tableUserDetails.content, tableUserDetails and tableUserDetailsList for both tables:

*** FIRST TABLE ***

print tableUserDetails.content = none

print tableUserDetails =

```
  <table class="user-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="headline txtBlue size15" style="width:80px">
                        About
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:10px">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="txtGrey size15">
                        Fume occasionnellement with Silhouette mince
                    </td>
                    <td width="25px;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="headline txtBlue size15">
                        City
                    </td>
                    <td class="txtGrey size15">
                        Paris Ile-de-France
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="headline txtBlue size15">
                        Details
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:10px">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="txtGrey size15">
                        26 year old Un homme, 185cm, Sans religion
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="headline txtBlue size15">
                        Ethnicity
                    </td>
                    <td class="txtGrey size15">
                        Caucasienne Balance with Châtains
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="headline txtBlue size15">
                        Intent
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:10px">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="txtGrey size15">
                        French.Kiss Cherche une relation amoureuse.
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="headline txtBlue size15" style="width:90px">
                        Education
                    </td>
                    <td class="txtGrey size15">
                        Diplôme universitaire/Licence
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="headline txtBlue size15">
                        Personnalité
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:10px">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td class="txtGrey size15">

                    </td>   <td>
                    </td>
                <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size15">Profession </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size15">
                                Visioconférence</span>
                        </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

print tableUserDetailsList = [u'About', u'Fume occasionnellement with Silhouette mince', u'City', u'Paris Ile-de-France', u'Details', u'26 year old Un homme, 185cm, Sans religion', u'Ethnic
ity', u'Caucasienne Balance with Ch\xe2tains', u'Intent', u'French.Kiss Cherche
une relation amoureuse.', u'Education', u'Dipl\xf4me universitaire/Licence', u'P
ersonnalit\xe9']

*** SECOND TABLE ***

print tableUserDetails.content = none

print tableUserDetails =

```
 <table width="85%" class="secondpart">
                    <tr height="25px">
                        <td width="200px">
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">I am Seeking a</span>
                        </td>
                        <td width="300px">
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Une femme</span>
                        </td>
                        <td width="25px">
                        </td>
                        <td width="200px">
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">For</span>
                        </td>
                        <td width="200px">
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Sorties</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25px">
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14"><a href='needs_test.aspx'>Needs Test</a></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14"><a href='needs_test.aspx'>


                                <a href="needs_view.aspx?id=38028200">View
                                    his
                                    relationship needs</a></a></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14"><a href='poftest.aspx'>Chemistry</a></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14"><a href='poftest.aspx'>

                                <a href="personality.aspx?id=26&user_id=41724176" rel="nofollow">View
                                    his
                                    chemistry results</a></a></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25px">
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Do you drink?</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Occasionnellement</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Do you want children?</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Non divulgué</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25px">
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Marital Status</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Célibataire</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Do you do drugs?</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Non</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr height="25px">
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Pets </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Aucun</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Eye Color</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Bruns</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr height="25px">
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Do you have a car? </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                N/A</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Do you have children?</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Non</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25px">
                        <td>
                         <span class="headline txtBlue size14">Longest Relationship</span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <span class="txtGrey size14">
                                Plus de 2 ans</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
```

print tableUserDetailsList = []

Comment: what does it mean that you cannot parse ? what is the result?

Comment: I cannot parse the second table = the list "tableUserDetailsList" is empty for the second table. I tried to print the content of "tableUserDetails". It prints the HTML of the table but when I try to parse it with findall("tr")/("td") like the first one, the list tableUserDetailsList is empty at the end. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Could you post the HTML you're trying to parse ? (at least the tables)

Comment: Add `tableUserDetails.content` and `tableUserDetailsList` for both the tables to your question. Also: (1) Why are you using the same variable names for unrelated variables? (2) Why have you pasted the same code twice, instead of iterating over a list containing the soups for the two tables?

Comment: morphyn > HTML added.

Comment: Anybhav > Posted for both tables + tableUserDetails. I used the same variable names/code because I wanted to emphasize the fact that I am doing exactly the same thing with the second table. Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
tableUserDetailsList = []
for row in tableUserDetails.findAll('tr'):
    for col in row.findAll('td'):
        contents = list(col.stripped_strings)
        if contents:
            contentTd = contents[0]
            print "TD Number %d : %s" % (i, contentTd)
            tableUserDetailsList.append(contentTd)
            i += 1
```

The problem was that your second table contains `spans`. The line break before the `span` was also interpreted as content and returned in the `col.contents` list.

It also works for the first table. As Anubhav commented, you should really consider iterating over the tables and not having the same code twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works perfectly. I am going to read more about stripped_strings. As Anubhav said, DNRY time now!

Answer (score 0):

Instead using table = soup.find('table')

Use table = soup.find_all('table')

This will return a list of tables in your html, and you can then pick the correct one from the list.